# Complexity of average maximum completion time

Tags: scheduling

There are $n$ jobs with different processing times, and they should be scheduled on $m$
identical machines such that the average (of all jobs, of all machines) maximum completion time (makespan) is minimized and under a certain time $T_{\max}$:

$$ \min_{\mathbf{y}}\;  \frac{1}{N}  \sum_{i \in \mathcal{N}} \sum_{j\in \mathcal{M}} y_{ij} \cdot \max_{\ell \in \mathcal{N}} \{ y_{\ell j} \}$$
$$ \text{s.t.} \sum_{i\in \mathcal{N}} \sum_{j\in \mathcal{M}} y_{ij} \cdot \max_{\ell \in \mathcal{N}} \{y_{\ell j}\} \leq T_{\max} $$
$$  \sum_{j\in \mathcal{M}} y_{ij} =1 , \forall i \in \mathcal{N}  $$
$$  y_{ij} \in \{0,1\}, \;  \forall i \in \mathcal{N}, j\in \mathcal{M}. $$

We came up with this problem as we want to schedule (offload) tasks generated by users to servers for processing. Does anyone know the complexity of this problem?

Comment: Are $y_{ij}$ and $y_{lj}$ the same variables?

Comment: Yes, they are the same, $y_{ij}$ denotes that task i is scheduled in the $j^{th}$ machine. However, for each task, we need the maximum of all tasks assigned to the specific server.

Comment: The $\max\{\}$ seems to be an unnecessary complication.  You can more simply express the same problem by omitting it in both places.

Comment: Also, you have not included the processing times anywhere.

Comment: Instead of $\underset{\lambda \in \mathcal{N}} \max{y_{\lambda j}}$
We have  $\underset{\lambda\in\mathcal{N}}{\max} \left\{y_{\lambda j}\cdot \frac{d_\lambda}{R_{\lambda j}} \right\}$, where $d_\lambda$ is the task size and $R_{\lambda j}$ the transmission rate. So actually this is the transmission time of each task towards a server. We have considered a special case to make it simpler. Is the $\max{}$ operator still unnecessary? What about the complexity? Thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your model should instead be expressed as follows.  For job $i\in\mathcal{N}$ and machine $j\in\mathcal{M}$, let $p_{ij}$ be the processing time.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{i\in \mathcal{N}} p_{ij} y_{ij} &\le z && \forall j\in \mathcal{M} \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_{i\in \mathcal{N}} p_{ij} y_{ij} &\le T_{\max} && \forall j\in \mathcal{M} \tag2\label2 \\
\sum_{j\in \mathcal{M}} y_{ij} &= 1 && \forall i \in \mathcal{N} \tag3\label3 \\
y_{ij} &\in \{0,1\} && \forall i \in \mathcal{N}, j\in \mathcal{M}
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} defines the makespan $z$.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces the total processing time limit on machine $m$.
Constraint \eqref{3} assigns each job to exactly one machine.

Comment: Is z the maximum makespan for each machine? If yes then the problem is NP-hard, right?

Comment: Yes, $z$ represents the makespan of the project (the maximum completion time across machines).  Yes, NP-hard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrelated-machines_scheduling

Comment: I think you can replace (2) with the domain constraint $z\in[0,T_{\max}]$.

Comment: Or just omit (2) and check it afterwards.